# Select rows containing xml node at any position in document

Tags: sql, xml, sql-server-2008

I am trying to return xml that has a specific attribute in sql.

The xml looks like this:

```
<Settings>
  <Item Name="ColorScheme" Type="XDocument">
  <ColorScheme>
     <ItemStyle Name="element-song" Title="Song" ForeColor="#0538ac" BackColor="#e8f1fa" Media="1" />
     <ItemStyle Name="element-song-print" Title="Song (print)" ForeColor="#0538ac" BackColor="" Media="2" />
     <ItemStyle Name="element-spot" Title="Spot" ForeColor="#048b27" BackColor="#e9ffee" Media="1" />
     <ItemStyle Name="element-spot-print" Title="Spot (print)" ForeColor="#048b27" BackColor="" Media="2" />
     <ItemStyle Name="element-programming" Title="Programming" ForeColor="#0538ac" BackColor="#e8f1fa" Media="1" />
     <ItemStyle Name="element-programming-print" Title="Programming (print)" ForeColor="#0538ac" BackColor="" Media="2" />
     <ItemStyle Name="element-continued-programming" Title="Continued programming" ForeColor="#0538ac" BackColor="#e8f1fa" Media="1" />
     <ItemStyle Name="element-continued-programming-print" Title="Continued programming (print)" ForeColor="#0538ac" BackColor="" Media="2" />
  </ColorScheme>
  </Item>
  <Item Name="SendWeeklyNewAccountEmail" Type="Boolean">False</Item>
  <Item Name="UseEstimatedDurationsForAnalysis" Type="Boolean">True</Item>
  <Item Name="CalendarStyle" Type="Int32">1</Item>
  <Item Name="IncludeAdExForAnalysis" Type="Boolean">True</Item>
</Settings>
```

the query I use to select these fields that contain the colorscheme attribute are:

```
SELECT * FROM CustomSettings WITH (NOLOCK)WHERE settings_xml.value('(/Settings/Item/@Name)[1]', 'varchar(25)') = 'ColorScheme' order by 1 desc
```

The problem I am running into is it only selects the xml that has ColorScheme as the first field. If its located further in the xml (which is a possibility) it doesnt get selected. I understand this is due to me having [1] in my query, but the query is not correcct if I remove this portion. So what do I put in its place to make it not position specific?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM CustomSettings 
WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE settings_xml.value('(/Settings/Item[@name="ColorScheme"]/@Name)[1]', 'varchar(25)') IS NOT NULL
order by 1 desc
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @x TABLE (x XML)

INSERT INTO @x 
VALUES ('<Settings>   <Item Name="ColorScheme" Type="XDocument">   <ColorScheme>      <ItemStyle Name="element-song" Title="Song" ForeColor="#0538ac" BackColor="#e8f1fa" Media="1" />      <ItemStyle Name="element-song-print" Title="Song (print)" ForeColor="#0538ac" BackColor="" Media="2" />      <ItemStyle Name="element-spot" Title="Spot" ForeColor="#048b27" BackColor="#e9ffee" Media="1" />      <ItemStyle Name="element-spot-print" Title="Spot (print)" ForeColor="#048b27" BackColor="" Media="2" />      <ItemStyle Name="element-programming" Title="Programming" ForeColor="#0538ac" BackColor="#e8f1fa" Media="1" />      <ItemStyle Name="element-programming-print" Title="Programming (print)" ForeColor="#0538ac" BackColor="" Media="2" />      <ItemStyle Name="element-continued-programming" Title="Continued programming" ForeColor="#0538ac" BackColor="#e8f1fa" Media="1" />      <ItemStyle Name="element-continued-programming-print" Title="Continued programming (print)" ForeColor="#0538ac" BackColor="" Media="2" />   </ColorScheme>   </Item>   <Item Name="SendWeeklyNewAccountEmail" Type="Boolean">False</Item>   <Item Name="UseEstimatedDurationsForAnalysis" Type="Boolean">True</Item>   <Item Name="CalendarStyle" Type="Int32">1</Item>   <Item Name="IncludeAdExForAnalysis" Type="Boolean">True</Item> </Settings> ')
, ('<Settings>  <Item Name="SendWeeklyNewAccountEmail" Type="Boolean">False</Item>   <Item Name="UseEstimatedDurationsForAnalysis" Type="Boolean">True</Item>   <Item Name="CalendarStyle" Type="Int32">1</Item>   <Item Name="IncludeAdExForAnalysis" Type="Boolean">True</Item> </Settings> )')
, ('<Settings>   <Item Name="IncludeAdExForAnalysis" Type="Boolean">True</Item>  <Item Name="ColorScheme" Type="XDocument">   <ColorScheme>      <ItemStyle Name="element-song" Title="Song" ForeColor="#0538ac" BackColor="#e8f1fa" Media="1" />      <ItemStyle Name="element-song-print" Title="Song (print)" ForeColor="#0538ac" BackColor="" Media="2" />      <ItemStyle Name="element-spot" Title="Spot" ForeColor="#048b27" BackColor="#e9ffee" Media="1" />      <ItemStyle Name="element-spot-print" Title="Spot (print)" ForeColor="#048b27" BackColor="" Media="2" />      <ItemStyle Name="element-programming" Title="Programming" ForeColor="#0538ac" BackColor="#e8f1fa" Media="1" />      <ItemStyle Name="element-programming-print" Title="Programming (print)" ForeColor="#0538ac" BackColor="" Media="2" />      <ItemStyle Name="element-continued-programming" Title="Continued programming" ForeColor="#0538ac" BackColor="#e8f1fa" Media="1" />      <ItemStyle Name="element-continued-programming-print" Title="Continued programming (print)" ForeColor="#0538ac" BackColor="" Media="2" />   </ColorScheme>   </Item>   <Item Name="SendWeeklyNewAccountEmail" Type="Boolean">False</Item>   <Item Name="UseEstimatedDurationsForAnalysis" Type="Boolean">True</Item>   <Item Name="CalendarStyle" Type="Int32">1</Item>  </Settings> ')


SELECT *
FROM @x x1
WHERE  x1.x.exist('(/Settings/Item[@Name="ColorScheme"])') = 1
```